# How can I change comment template?

Tags: 8, comments

When we send a comment, it shows:

```
<article>comment</article>
```

When we send a reply to that comment, it shows:

```
<article>comment</article>
<div class="indented"><article>reply comment</article></div>
```

Now I want to show *reply comment* in the first article tag.

```
<article>comment
<div class="indented"><article>reply comment</article></div>
</article>
```

Comment: You will probably need to use a template preprocess override to nest the comments array.

Comment: Good but how can I do this?

Comment: You need to copy comment.html.twig (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/8.2.x/search/comment) and to your theme, make your changes, then clear your cache.